# Integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-a x^2(x^2-\pi^2)}\cos(2\pi a x^3)}{\cosh x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-a x^2(x^2-\pi^2)}\cos(2\pi a x^3)}{\cosh x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\pi^4 a/16}.$$
Note the unusual appearance of $x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4$.

Comment: What's the question? Do you want a proof of this?

Comment: Where does it come from? Maple and WA can't find the right-hand side on my machine even for some fixed $a$.

Comment: From the looks of it, this is one of those nasty oscillatory integrals, which are handled best in the complex plane using the method of stationary phase / saddle point method.

Comment: Is $$ I = 4\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\exp \left(a\pi^2 \left(n+\frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \left(\pi^2 \left(n+\frac{1}{2} \right)^2+ \pi^2  \right) + 2a\pi^4 \left(n+\frac{1}{2} \right)^3 \right) $$ ?

Comment: @rajb245: the OP is asserting an exact result (as illustrated below).  Why would you use techniques to provide asymptotic approximations?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, I thought he was providing an approximation for large $a$.  Now I see that the form of the right hand side doesn't have a term like $1/a$ so I was just plain wrong.

Comment: Since you are new here, may I call your attention to the "About" link. Especially the segment on accepting answers. As you might consider doing for the incredible answer below.

Answer (score 26):

**EDIT**
@Random Variable found an error in sign in the exponent of the integrand. This is corrected, and does not affect the result.  Many thanks to RV for carefully reading through.

To evaluate this integral, consider the following integral in the complex plane:

$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2+\pi^2/4)^2}$$

where $C=C_1+C_2+C_3+C_4+C_5+C_6$ as illustrated below:

[image]

$$\int_{C_1} \frac{dz}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2+\pi^2/4)^2} = \int_{i \pi/2}^{R+i \pi/2} \frac{dx}{\sinh{x}} e^{-a (x^2+\pi^2/4)^2}$$
$$\int_{C_2} \frac{dz}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2+\pi^2/4)^2} = i\int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2} \frac{dy}{\sinh{(R+iy)}} e^{-a [(R+i y)^2+\pi^2/4]^2} $$
$$\int_{C_3} \frac{dz}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2+\pi^2/4)^2} = \int_{R-i \pi/2}^{-i \pi/2} \frac{dx}{\sinh{x}} e^{-a (x^2+\pi^2/4)^2}$$
$$\int_{C_4} \frac{dz}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2+\pi^2/4)^2} = \int_{-\pi/2}^{-\epsilon} \frac{dy}{\sin{y}} e^{-a (y^2-\pi^2/4)^2} $$
$$\int_{C_5} \frac{dz}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2+\pi^2/4)^2} = i \epsilon\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{d\phi \, e^{i \phi}}{\sinh{(\epsilon e^{i \phi}})} e^{-a [\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}+\pi^2/4]^2} $$
$$\int_{C_6} \frac{dz}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2+\pi^2/4)^2} = \int_{\epsilon}^{\pi/2} \frac{dy}{\sin{y}} e^{-a (y^2-\pi^2/4)^2} $$

We intend to take $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$.  In this case, it should be clear that the integral over $C_2$ will vanish in the former limit.  Also, the integrals over $C_4$ and $C_6$ cancel each other out as the sum is an integral over an odd integrand over a symmetric interval.

We are then left with the integrals over $C_1$, $C_3$, and $C_5$.  The sum of the first two integrals, over $C_1$ and $C_3$, is

$$\underbrace{\int_{i \pi/2}^{\infty+i \pi/2} \frac{dz}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2+\pi^2/4)^2}}_{z=x+i \pi/2} + \underbrace{\int_{\infty-i \pi/2}^{-i \pi/2} \frac{dz}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2+\pi^2/4)^2}}_{z=x-i \pi/2} = \\ -i \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\cosh{x}} e^{-a x^2 (x+i \pi)^2} + i \int_{\infty}^0 \frac{dx}{\cosh{x}} e^{-a x^2 (x-i \pi)^2}$$

which is

$$-i \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\cosh{x}} e^{-a x^2 (x^2-\pi^2)} \left [ e^{i 2 \pi a x^3} + e^{-i 2 \pi a x^3}\right] = -i 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\cosh{x}} e^{-a x^2 (x^2-\pi^2)} \cos{2 \pi a x^3} $$

The integral over $C_5$ is, in the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, is

$$i \epsilon\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{d\phi \, e^{i \phi}}{\sinh{(\epsilon e^{i \phi}})} e^{-a [\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}+\pi^2/4]^2} \approx i \epsilon\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{d\phi \, e^{i \phi}}{\epsilon e^{i \phi}} e^{-a (\pi^2/4)^2} = i \pi e^{-a \pi^4/16}$$

By Cauchy's Theorem, the sum of the integrals over these contours is zero.  Thus we get

$$-i 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\cosh{x}} e^{-a x^2 (x^2-\pi^2)} \cos{2 \pi a x^3} + i \pi e^{-a \pi^4/16}=0$$

The result follows.

**ADDENDUM**

Apparently I made one edit too many and it was pointed out that the solution, clean as it is now, has become a *deux ex machina*.  Fair enough: I will put back the motivation behind the sleight of hand.

Basically, when I looked at the integral, it screamed "complete the square in the exponentials."  So, I rewrote the integral as the real part of

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\cosh{x}} e^{-a x^2 (x+i \pi)^2}$$

The problem is that, while tempting to make a substitution like $u=x (x+i \pi)$, you end up having to follow a curve in the complex plane.  Better, I thought, to work with something more symmetric if I am going to work in the complex plane anyway.  Thus I let $x=y-i \pi/2$ so that the above integral becomes

$$-i \int_{i \pi/2}^{\infty+i \pi/2} \frac{dy}{\sinh{y}} e^{-a (y^2+\pi^2/4)^2}$$

And to me it became clear that the contour $C$ above would be useful once I did this.  The rest is, well, above.

Comment: +1. You are like a machine for doing integrals. (I mean this as a compliment.)

Comment: that's very good answer , integral machine . (+1)

Comment: I guess a consensus has been reached.

Comment: I think your evaluation was better before you edited it.  The way it's written now gives no insight into how you picked $f(z)$ and the contour.

Comment: @RandomVariable: Interesting.  I thought that first piece cluttered and was the equivalent of digital chicken scratch.  I'll put it back in next chance I get, a little more coherent.

Comment: This is a (correct) consequence of my conjecture:$$Re\int_0^{\infty}F(x^2+i\pi x){\rm sech} x dx=(\pi/2)F(\pi^2/4)$$ for which I am seeking sufficient conditions on $F$. It works when $F$ is a real function which posesses an inverse Laplace transform, e.g. and decays sufficiently rapidly in the upper half plane, but for others, as well.

Comment: @larry: using the method described above, I get, for the RHS, $$\frac{\pi}{2} F \left ( -\frac{\pi^2}{4} \right)$$ note the negative sign in the argument of $F$.

Comment: The above of course is subject to particular constraints on $F$ similar to the vanishing of the integral along $C_2$.

Comment: @Ron: Maybe I'm not thinking straight because it's late.  But shouldn't the contour integral be $$  \oint_C \frac{dz}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2 {\color{red} + }\pi^2/4)^2} \ ?$$

Comment: @RandomVariable: uhhhh...you may be right.  How could none of us have picked up on that?  Better re-check in the morning when I have had enough sleep.

Comment: I don't know if you rechecked or not.  But it still looks like it should be $ \displaystyle f(z) = \frac{1}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2 {\color{red} + }\pi^2/4)^2}$.  That won't change the contribution from the indentation. And where it will make a difference, you treated $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2 {\color{green} - }\pi^2/4)^2}$ like it was $ \displaystyle f(z) = \frac{1}{\sinh{z}} e^{-a (z^2 {\color{red} + }\pi^2/4)^2}$.

Comment: @RandomVariable: derivation corrected, and credit given to you.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.  It's funny that on here you're thanking me, while on AoPS I'm being ridiculed.

Comment: @RandomVariable: huh?  Why?

Comment: Wonderful, Ron.  But, may I ask something stupid?. Below where you write, "We are then left with the integrals over C1, C3, and C5. The sum of the first two integrals, over C1 and C3, is...",   how do you go from and e exponent of  $-a(z^{2}+\frac{\pi^{2}}{4})^{2}$ to $-ax^{2}(x+\pi i)^{2}$ after making the $z=x+\pi i/2$ sub?.   This may be dumb, but I can not see where the extra terms went, and I really enjoy thoroughly understanding your solutions.

Comment: Forget my previous comment. DUH. I tried deleting, but it was too late.

Comment: RV is probably being ridiculed on AoPS because there are certain regulars who have huge egos and do not like it if someone as cognizant as RV points out a mistake.

Comment: @RonGordon A nice answer (+1).